# VBA: include the subroutine to the condtion

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

Could you help me please with the syntax: I would like to include the subroutine FRAIS_bis() in my code, but when I'm writing the code it appears in red.

```
 Worksheets("5 - Tarification").Range("L26").Interior.ColorIndex = 15

    If Worksheets("5 - Tarification").Range("X12").Value = False Then
    If Len(Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("E16").Value) > 0
    Then
        FRAIS_bis()
        
    Else
    Worksheets("5 - Tarification").Range("X4").Value = False
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please, try just removing the parenthesis. Use only `FRAIS_bis`...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you, but my lines are still in red  :( I added the image to my code.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily move keywords such as `Then` to the next line.

Comment: But you said "the subroutine FRAIS_bis()"... I can see now that the line above. Please, move `Then` word on the end of its above position, or place ` _` at the end of the above code line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Call` before the name of the subroutine (or not use brackets), everything is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures).

Comment: Thank you, my lines are still in red  :( I added the image.

Comment: You need to let the word `THEN` be on the same line as the `IF`.